# Basic Auth with Jquery and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I try to get access to a directory or file that is protected with .htaccess with this code:

```
        function make_base_auth(user, password) {
      var tok = user + ':' + password;
      var hash = btoa(tok);
      return "Basic " + hash;
    }
```

and

```
            $.ajax
          ({
            type: "GET",
            url: "prot/index.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            data: {username: username, password: password},
            headers  : { Authorization: make_base_auth(username, password) },
            success: function (){
                alert('geschafft'); 
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                console.log('Fehler: ' + thrownError+ "; status:  " +xhr.status);
            } 
        });
```

But I get the error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
>   and the status 200

I also tried it with beforeSend and xhr.SetRequestHeader with the same result.

What's wrong ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax

Comment: You are passing username and password as plain-text.  This is not secure.